# Dictionary accession numbers

Tags: python, dictionary

**Edit, I've restated this question, hopefully it isn't as stupid as before!*

I want to create a dictionary matching  accession numbers to species names. I formatted my file so that it look like this:

'AM158981':Brucella,pinnipedialis,Brucellaceae,
'AM158980':Brucella,suis,Brucellaceae,
'AM158982':Brucella,ceti,Brucellaceae,
'AM158979':Brucella,abortus,Brucellaceae,

etc......

I want to open this file so that it becomes a dictionary. I wrote this to try and open it and make the accession numbers the keys for the dictionary:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

reader = open("acsn.txt")

result = {}
for row in reader:
    key = row[0]
    if key in result:
        pass
    result[key] = row[1:]
print result
```

The "key = row[0]" line is making the first letter of the accession number the key. I realize that using [0] is just returning the first character of the string, but I'm not sure how to make it so that the first 'word' (e.g. AM158981) becomes the key.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: ... and the problem is? Parsing the string? Choosing the data structure? Something else?

Comment: Hi @Jen! Did you read the SO rules?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some help.

First, it is better to use the `with` construct to open files in Python, like this:

```
with open('/tmp/src.txt','r') as src:
    for line in src:
        print line.strip()
```

That should print your file intact like so:

```
\>D50541 Abiotrophia defectiva   Aerococcacea
\>AB303221 Acanthopleuribacter pedis     Acanthopleuribacteraceae
\>AJ812213 Acaricomes phytoseiuli        Micrococcaceae
```

Now you just need to parse each line of the data. Just based on personal preference, I would use a regex, but there are many ways to do it.  [Here is an example regex](http://www.regex101.com/r/kE3kF6) that works on your line of data.

Here is the same example regex in Python:

```
import re

data={}        
with open('/tmp/src.txt','r') as src:
    for line in src:
        m=re.search(r'>([^\s]*)\s(.*)$',line)       
        if m:
            data[m.group(1)]=m.group(2)  

print data
```

Prints:

```
{'AB303221': 'Acanthopleuribacter pedis     Acanthopleuribacteraceae', 'AJ812213': 'Acaricomes phytoseiuli        Micrococcaceae', 'D50541': 'Abiotrophia defectiva   Aerococcacea'}
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Best way to thank someone is to accept the answer (check mark on the left of the answer...)

Answer (score 2):

Python code:

```
data = """>D50541 Abiotrophia defectiva Aerococcacea
>AB303221 Acanthopleuribacter pedis Acanthopleuribacteraceae
>AJ812213 Acaricomes phytoseiuli Micrococcaceae"""

dict(row[1:].split(" ", 1) for row in data.split("\n"))
```

Output:

```
{'AB303221': 'Acanthopleuribacter pedis Acanthopleuribacteraceae',
 'AJ812213': 'Acaricomes phytoseiuli Micrococcaceae',
 'D50541': 'Abiotrophia defectiva Aerococcacea'}
```

**Edit**

If the data is read from the file `input.txt`, do this:

```
dict(row[1:].split(" ", 1) for row in open("input.txt").read().split("\n") if row)
```

Comment: How would I format that so I could have a script access a file (there are MANY lines!) and do this to the whole file?

Comment: @Jen added code to read from file. How many are "MANY"?

Comment: Thanks for the added code! There are 9701 lines of accession numbers

Comment: @Jen 9701 is not many.

Comment: Okay, so I tried the new code that reads from a file, how would I check to see if it wored, would I type at the command line: dict['#one of the accession numbers'] ?

Comment: hahaha, to me it seems like a lot!